# Can we have multiple subapi with Swagger?

Tags: node.js, requirejs, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm developing a system with nodeJS and I use requireJS and swagger.
Now, I'm preparing to create new version of my site.
Can we have multiple subapi with swagger.
I mean, currently my swagger api is located at localhost:2052/docs and I want my system have 2 apis:

- localhost:2052/docs and
- localhost:2052/v2.0/docs

Is it possible with swagger, if yes, how?